# Corona sdk audio not playing

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have been trying to test out some stuff in Corona sdk because I want to make a math game that will have levels of math for children up to adults.  Here is the code I have (It is just a test)

Main.lua:

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
local ButtonClickedSound = audio.loadSound( "Button Clicked Sound.wav") 
local FailSound = audio.loadSound( "Fail Sound.wav" )
local SucessSound = audio.loadSound( "Sucess Sound.mp3" )
-- Physics

local physics = require('physics')
physics.start()

local FailSoundChannel = audio.play(FailSound)
-- local gameBg = display.newImage('\Images\Background')
```

Config.lua:

```
application =
{
    content =
    {
        width = 320,
        height = 480,
        scale = "letterbox"
    },
}
```

I have a sound in my file and everything is correctly named.  Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: try escaping the spaces in the name `"Fail\ Sound.wav"`

Comment: try playing the sound with a delay, since it may take some time to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
local ButtonClickedSound = audio.loadSound( "Button Clicked Sound.wav") 
local FailSound = audio.loadSound( "Fail Sound.wav" )
local SucessSound = audio.loadSound( "Sucess Sound.mp3" )
 -- Physics

physics = require('physics')
physics.start()

local function delay()
  local FailSoundChannel = audio.play(FailSound)
end 

timer.performWithDelay(100, delay, 1)
```

try this and see. And more over check whether the file names and path are correct.